# How can I deal with this list with ruby?

Tags: ruby, list, zip, tuples

I want to make a list as follow to be a list of <strike>tuples</strike> arrays:

```
['Daisy', '80', '90', 'Amy', '90', '100', 'Anna', '88', '99']
```

change to:

```
[['Daisy', '80', '90'], ['Amy', '90', '100'], ['Anna', '88', '99']]
```

how can I do this elegantly with ruby?

Comment: @muistooshort sorry, I use python too much recently, I make a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Enumberable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
list = ['Daisy', '80', '90', 'Amy', '90', '100', 'Anna', '88', '99']
list.each_slice(3).to_a
=> [["Daisy", "80", "90"], ["Amy", "90", "100"], ["Anna", "88", "99"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that does not require you to know how many numbers you have for each person:

```
my_list = ['Daisy', '80', '90', 'Amy', '90', '100', 'Anna', '88', '99']

non_digit_word = -> x{x[/\D+/]}

p my_list.slice_before(&non_digit_word).to_a #=> [["Daisy", "80", "90"], ["Amy", "90", "100"], ["Anna", "88", "99"]]
```